# ColdFusion how to print curl request response in page

Tags: curl, coldfusion

Using ColdFusion, I'm trying to figure out how to make a simple HTTP GET request and display it in a page.

From what i've been reading, [`cfhttp`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_g-h_09.html) is what I can use to perform the request, but how to do print the response out in the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the "response" part of the file  do this:

```
<cfoutput>#cfhttp.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

So for example:

```
<Cfhttp url="http://www.google.com" resolveurl="yes"/>

<cfoutput>#cfhttp.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

Will output the google homepage to your screen. Note that resolveURL tranlates any relative path in the called content to absolute - so src="/images/blah.gif" becomes src="http://www.google.com/images/blah.gif". That's handy if you are trying to display anything :)

Answer (score 0):

you can dump out your response by simply doing

```
<cfdump var="#cfhttp.filecontent#">
```

unless you give it a value in the `result` attribute, then you would dump out that variable.